# Make function with (Maybe a) parameter "generic"

Tags: haskell, type-inference

```hs
let updateFunc = updatedMaybeProperty srcTitle targetTitle :: (Title -> Maybe a) -> Maybe a
    _ = updateFunc (titleVersion      :: Title -> Maybe Text)
    _ = updateFunc (titleYearProduced :: Title -> Maybe Integer)
```

I get this error in line 3:

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘Text’ with ‘Integer’
      Expected type: Title -> Maybe Text
        Actual type: Title -> Maybe Integer
    • In the first argument of ‘updateFunc’, namely
        ‘(titleYearProduced :: Title -> Maybe Integer)’
```

Apparently, in line 2, the compiler infers the type for `Maybe a` and decides `a` must always be `Text`.

How can I prevent this and make `updateFunc` "generic" so that it works with different types for `a`?

Comment: This is not possible by design. Use `Either`.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot use `Either` because 1) I have more datatypes than `Text` and `Integer` and 2) only `Maybe` is possible by design (Yesod/Persistent framework). Maybe there is a compiler extension for such cases? Otherwise I have to duplicate `updateFunc` and use different names for it.

Comment: Make a new datatype to encapsulate the options. E.g.: `data MyReturnType = ReturnText Text | ReturnInteger Integer | ...`. But maybe if your `updateFunc` does totally different things, you should consider seperating it or writing a typeclass.

Comment: Hm, `updateFunc` does not even touch the value of type `a` inside the `Maybe`. Since  `updateFunc` is only used as a helper in one function, I think it's easiest to copy the first line and call it `updateFuncT`, `updateFuncI`, ...

Comment: What's the type of targetTitle? Are you sure that this type annotation shouldn't be in a separate line?

Comment: Why are you defining `_` twice?

Answer (score 6):

Try annotating the binding, not the expression.

```
let updateFunc :: (Title -> Maybe a) -> Maybe a
    updateFunc = updatedMaybeProperty srcTitle targetTitle
    _ = updateFunc (titleVersion      :: Title -> Maybe Text)
    _ = updateFunc (titleYearProduced :: Title -> Maybe Integer)
```